# Loading dll from Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, dll

I am trying to develop extensions for chrome and firefox that will communicate with my main program. I have developed a native library for the communication and in the extensions I just need to load the dll and call a method.

For Firefox I have no issue. I did it easily using `ctypes.open("mydll.dll");`

But for Chrome, as far as I know, currently there is no way to do that.
because in one hand NPAPI is being phased out and in the other hand NaCI/ppapi runs in a sandbox.

Am I missing something or it's really impossible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find an easy way to do this?

Comment: No, not really, instead I went for a totally different approach that did not need Chrome extension implementation. But thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Native Messaging is the recommended solution for an extension that needs to communicate with an application.

Comment: That's right. But the answer to my question is "yes"?
so there is no way to load a dll from a chrome extension?
because it's very important to me, I need to reuse the code. It would have lots of overhead to rewrite everything in Native Messaging.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should create an exe that wraps your DLL and then register it as a Native Messaging host.
In your exe, you would parse the JSON sent from Chrome and convert it into variables that you pass to methods in the DLL.